# blender renders wrong portions of video strips

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video

Here is the situation
I loaded several video files, edited the strips, did some cuttings, and made a sequence that I'd like to get rendered, added some audio files, did same kind of work on them.

But here is the thing, after I render this sequence, in the resulting file I get portions of video fragments that I cutted out while editing, And I don't see them in video view in blender.

What can be the reason for that?

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1x-xi34dnYFYUhfQXQ4WUNjdVE/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: You need to mute the original strips

Comment: could you upload a screenshot from your VSE?

Comment: What format is the original video in?

Comment: @cegaton it's avi file

Comment: What Codec? how was it generated? Also check that the framerate of your project matches that of your video?

Comment: and btw all the audio strips were on 1 channel, then I made a meta strip from all (audio+video) strips, after pressed Alt+G, and the audio strips appeared on different channels. I don't know why

Comment: @cegaton, why should the frame rates match? I want to make a video a bit faster

Comment: Detected file format: AVI (Audio Video Interleaved) (libavformat)
[lavf] stream 0: video (mpeg4), -vid 0
VIDEO:  1920x1072  15.000 fps    0.0 kbps ( 0.0 kB/s)
VO: [xv] 1920x1072 => 1920x1072 Planar YV12

Comment: I made this file by converting with ffmpeg from ogv, which was made by recordmydesktop programm

Comment: I believe the issue you are experincing is because of thoe mismatching framerates. There are tools within the VSE to alter the speed of video.

Comment: @cegaton, actually the frame rate of the file matches that of the project, I did not set it faster, just wanted to do that. Sorry for confusion

Comment: @Denis I don't see any strips other than those I want to render, if I mute them, I don't have any video at all

Comment: could you upload the blendfile or is it to big?

Comment: Could you isolate one little piece of the file where the problem occour and send it with a portion of the file with video? Or make a video of you showing the issue? The structure of your file seems ok, so the input video should to be somehow involved. Does it has the same behaviour with other files too?

Comment: Sometimes Blender has issues decoding the input video (FFMPEG issue) and thus your edits and cuts might be cut to the wrong time. Using Proxy should help.

Comment: @MikePan, I enabled a proxy for this strip, rebuilt it, ran th rendering again,

No changes, strip rendered resulting in video different from what is in VSE

Comment: @Carlo it was a single file, I just montaged it a bit

Comment: @alirustam, you didn't pack the videos in the blendfile. To do this go to file --> external data --> pack all into.blend

Comment: @alirustam , once you build the proxy, does the preview look correct? If not, you need to recut the video using the proxy as guide. But ultimately, this is likely a bug with FFMPEG.

Comment: I noticed your blender is 4 version old.  Your screen cap says 2.71 and I have 2.75.  Try updating it first.

Comment: @cybernard, I tried it allready with newest version, didn't help

Comment: You cannot pack video into a .blend file. Sorry. It also looks like you are editing a screen cap, these videos are notoriously incompatible with current versions of Blender. Best suggestion is to transcode your source file into something less compressed first, then edit that.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27452/discussion-on-question-by-ali-rustam-blender-renders-wrong-portions-of-video-str).

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41720/2843

Comment: Try using: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49219/2843 - does it help?

Answer (score 1):

That's most likely a problem due to a broken Video file. The internally used ffmpeg libraries don't work too well with some video formats and are not able to always provide the frames without artifacts and in the right order one by one. I bet your Screencast software didn't do a good job in encoding your footage.

So try to repair your footage. And then instead of using RecordMyDesktop to capture your screen you should use [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/download#linux) recording to file, not LiveStream. It should provide you with non-problematic footage that you can use with Blender without problems.