# Video sequence editing, cutting strips

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm trying some video editing with Blender and for now just wanna do some simple cuts. Whatever I do the strips keep some frames from what I thought should have been cut as soon as I start moving the strips around.

I know what happens under the hood as documented here for example: https://www.blender.org/manual/de/editors/sequencer/usage.html#moving-and-modifying-strips , but I still can't figure out how to do a simple cut like you can for example in Premiere Elements.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46596/2843

Comment: I have a dim feeling that it might also have something to do with this. The video im importing is a video capture from the XBox-App on Windows 10. Its recorded with this odd 24,97xxx fps and im setting the fps in blender to 25, but it still might cause a problem?

Comment: Seriously. Blender VSE is way too confusing. I feel like they could make things that should be super simple, super confusing and complicated.

Answer (score 11):

In the VSE you can cut a strip at the current frame by pressing <kbd>K</kbd>, which gives a "soft cut". You can also perform a "hard cut" at the current frame by using <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>

The two strips resulting from a cut still know the video that they are from and frames that were "cut" from the strip can still be recovered.

The difference between a hard and soft cut is that with a soft cut you can drag the start of the clip to recover frames before the cut, while with a hard cut this will duplicate the frame at the cut to the adjusted start of the clip. This works the same for the end of the strip.

In both cases you can adjust the start and end frame by adjusting the strip input properties - press <kbd>N</kbd> to show the properties region.

[image: strip input properties]

Comment: Thanks, the trim durations is what im messing around with currently. If im right you should remove the first and last frame AFTER the HARD cut because they are just copies of what has been cut out? Will try this later...;-)

Comment: Thanks! For me, it was the usage of the Trim Duration (soft) values that enabled me to simply cut away a bit of the start and ends. Do your hard cut first, note down the end frame. Put the end frame value in the Trim Duration (soft) box for both audio and video. Delete the other hard cut strip.

Comment: I tried Shift+K and I still cant get rid of the beginning of a video Clip. How to I remove it for good?

Comment: @XBuilder Cutting a strip will turn it into two strips, you select and delete the one you don't want. If you are referring to the video file, this is not affected by cutting in the VSE, you need to edit the VSE strips and then render the edited result to a new file.

Comment: @sambler , I tried to Shift+K the strip in two, and delete the first one, I even just tried setting the start time past the part I wanted to delete and rendering just the strip in a new blender VSE editor and it still rendered the beginning frames I tried to delete.

Answer (score 3):

When you press <kbd>K</kbd> in the *Blender VSE* you will have a "soft" cut meaning you can always move the handles (left and right arrows) and get the frames that has been cut.
I suggest to follow [this (and the other)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pw-GPKEMNxY&index=5&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4) tutorial for VSE 
I've discovered today, the guy it's exceptionally clear in his explanations

Comment: Thanks, I aready know this series and also recommend it!