# What does the frame_offset_end/Trim Duraion (soft) mean?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I've recently started making scripts to assist in my video editing, and it's already helped me out tremendously!  Now I want to make a script that automatically changes the video offset of all the selected strips by a set amount.

In doing this, I noticed a very confusing property about trimmed video clips.  For the Trim Duration (soft), the `frame_offset_start` of clips makes sense because it's the frame of the original clip where this cut begins.  However, the `frame_offset_end` seems to make absolutely no sense.  Its value is lower than the start value, but it's not the length of the clip and it's not the end frame.  When I increase the value, the clip gets shorter!  What is going on?

[image: Trim Duration(soft):81097-18536]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, `frame_offset_start` it is how many frames are cropped from start.

And same logic for `frame_offset_end`, but not from the start, from the **end** of strip!

So, If you increase that value, it will be crop more from **end** of the strip, and it will be shorter

Answer (score 1):

Hard and soft cut, and the differences between them, explained here: [Video sequence editing, cutting strips](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48484/video-sequence-editing-cutting-strips)