# How to make a 3gpp file usable for the movie clip editor ?

Tags: video, file-format

I have a movie file in the 3gpp format (shot with android smart phone, using Linux).
I switched into the movie clip editor and clicked on the open-button to import it as footage. Yet this file is not displayed in blenders file browser. 
How do I continue from here?

Should I convert this file into another one, and if yes with what program into what format ?

Should I use an addon for blender if possible ?

Comment: convert your video into a format that blender can use: like quicktime, avi or h264. or into an image sequence.

Comment: i found a solution, do you know avconv ? avconv -i file1.3gp -f mp4 file2.mp4

Comment: Try out reading it with AviSynth, compare: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41720/2843

Comment: After you found your solution you should add a quick answer for others to be able to accomplish this task as well.

Answer (score 5):

This question comes up pretty high in searches so I thought I'd add what worked for me - converting it to mp4 with ffmpeg:

`ffmpeg -i originalvid.3gp -q:v 0 -q:a 0 -strict -2 targetvid.mp4`

This keeps the video (q:v 0) and audio (q:a 0) at the maximum possible quality.

Comment: This takes ages and seems it is encoding it again. Can't imagine that re-encoding does not loose quality. Is there no other way to convert without re-encoding? The same codecs are supported by both formats, aren't they?

Comment: This makes sense, you are probably right. I don't know how I came to this conclusion 3 years ago. I've edited the answer, hopefully it's accurate now. I don't know to achieve a Blender-usable conversion without re-encoding though.

Comment: Thanks. for my video, the resulting mp4 was less than 1/3 of the size of the original 3gp in terms of file size. I know this is a blender site, but I need to convert it for another purpose, and any hints how to change the container from 3gp to mp4 without touching the content itself would be nice to read. I am very disappointed by my android producing 3gp and all usable video software ignoring this format. I have not found any solution of how to use my android to record video that I could process further without hours of lossy conversion, which is sort of surprise in this media-intensive ages.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me