# H.264 exported video stutters in windows media player & won't load in Premier editor

Tags: export, video

When run in Windows media player or the W10 TV&film player there are duplicated frames ...f21,22,22,23  or even freames in the wrong place. I have loaded them back into Blender and stepped through the frames which appear to be in the right place (when viewed inside Blender's VSL)

Does anyone know anything about this, experienced the same problem, found a solution?

Also, I prefer to edit in Premiere, but when it loads these Blender h.264 files the frames come in some strangely partially random form... 1,1,1,1,2,3,4......18, 19, 1, 20,

Comment: (I uploaded the special test clip to youtube and it ran smoothly.)

Comment: Yeah, the FFMPEG Plugin is a bit rough. You need a proper decoder for H.264 providing you every exact single frame. Most likely the video should be indexed before to be read out properly afterwards by the decoder. L-Smash is doing a great job here. See my answer [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41720/2843).